# Test to Understand Objective-C Vs Pointers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have wrote a test code to understand Objective C vs C pointers. Here is the code..

eg:

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *sec_mut;
    if (array) {
        [array addObject:@"My"];
         [array addObject:@"name"];
         [array addObject:@"is"];
         [array addObject:@"BoB"];

            sec_mut = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            if (sec_mut) {
                for (id obj in array) { // Is it allocating new object and adding or only points to already existing memory (just adding address)?
                    [sec_mut addObject:obj]; 
                }
            }
    }

    [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    for (id obj in sec_mut) {
        NSLog(@"str is %@\n",obj);
    }
```

Output: 
 str is My
 str is name
 str is is
 str is BoB

Even though I've deleted object at index zero all 4 object are displaying properly in new array, so it is not only pointing and its having its own object, Am I right? or Is it a dangling pointer?

thanx

Comment: Removing a pointer from an array wouldn't free the pointed-to memory in C either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When inserting objects into Cocoa collections, objects are generally **not copied,** only retained. (I. e., yes, only the pointers are used to reference the objects.)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if you had two mail men who knew your address, if got rid of one of them, the other would still know where you live.

You're not actually deleting the object, just a reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

H2CO3 is right, obj-c uses reference-counting which can be a smart memory management way.Both array and sec_mut keeps their own reference to the real object but not a copied one.You can read something about reference-counting tech for details.